# Binary file data reading incorrectly in Fortran 90

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, binaryfiles, file-read

I'm reading in a binary file written in a different program.  The open & read statements seem to be successful, I had help in a previous post.  However, the data read in does not match the file.  I've initialized the 2D array but after reading in the file, the array does not hold the data but looks to be an uninitialized array.  I've posted the code below for the read and the print out of the array.  Any thoughts?

```
       allocate(dummy(imax,jmax))

       dummy = 0.0
       open(unit=io, file=trim(input), access='direct', iostat=ioer, &
            status='old', action='READ', recl=imax*jmax*4)

       if(ioer/=0) then
        print*, 'Cannot open file'
       else
        print*,'success opening file'
       end if

       j=0
       k=0
       read(unit=io,rec=1,iostat=ioer) dummy!(j,k)
       if(ioer/=0) then
         print*, 'Cannot open file'
       else
         print*,'success opening file'
       end if

       size: do j=1, imax
           do k=1, jmax
             if(dummy(j,k) > 0.) print*,'i-',j,'j-',k,'frp-',dummy(j,k)
           end do 
       end do size
       print*,'j-',j,'k-',k
```

Here is the original write:

```
  out_file = trim(output_dir)//'SEVIRI_FRP_.08deg_'//trim(season)//'.bin'

  print*, out_file
  print*, i_max,' i_max,',j_max,' j_max'

  open (io, file = out_file, access = 'direct', status = 'replace', recl = i_max*j_max*4)

  write(io, rec = 1) sev_frp
  write(io, rec = 2) count_sev_frp
  write(io, rec = 3) sum_sev_frp
```

This is what is a portion of what is printing out:

```
  i-         600 j-         213 frp-  4.1759680E-08
  i-         600 j-         220 frp-  8.8314310E-18
  i-         600 j-         221 frp-  2.7975964E-36
  i-         600 j-         246 frp-   461506.1    
  i-         600 j-         254 frp-   19.79016    
  i-         600 j-         255 frp-  2.0032716E-22
  i-         600 j-         260 frp-  1.0871451E+24
  j-         601 k-         401
```

This is the same portion of what it should be:

```
  i-         600 j-         213 frp-   13.6999998    
  i-         600 j-         218 frp-   63.2000008    
  i-         600 j-         220 frp-   29.1416683    
  i-         600 j-         221 frp-   31.8032303    
  i-         600 j-         229 frp-   39.5000000    
  i-         600 j-         232 frp-   55.4714279    
  i-         600 j-         246 frp-   54.2200012    
  i-         600 j-         254 frp-   13.1636362    
  i-         600 j-         255 frp-   10.9028578    
  i-         600 j-         258 frp-   24.6888885    
  i-         600 j-         259 frp-   13.5619040    
  i-         600 j-         260 frp-   11.4000006    
  n-         601 m-         401
```

The declaration/allocation statements:

```
 real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: dummy

 allocate(dummy(imax,jmax))

 dummy = 0.0
```

These are the same in both the write/read & `imax` is 600 `jmax` is 400

Comment: @francescalus, I added the write above.  I read your statement before but I did not understand that `iostat=` was a format statement, I was under the impression it was an error check on the statement used.  I took it out of the open/read statements and it's building now.

Comment: It ran as before, I have the same incorrect data within the array and the indexes do not match either.

Comment: Oh, got it :)  I didn't know the `*` was still in the statement.  I have been (again) trying different types of reads to see what would happen, trying to find my error.  That run did not compile.

Comment: as said before, there are many sources of i/o errors. The way you use `iostat` you are hiding potentially useful error messages and replacing with a generic / less meaningful 'cannot open' message. (not to mention you probbly want to `stop` on an error )

Comment: is `sev_frp` the same type and dimensioned the same as `dummy` ?

Comment: Ok, so with `iostat` out of the statement, should other possible errors show?

Comment: Yes, both are 'real, allocatable, dimension(:,:)' and both are allocated with the same number of indexes [(imax,jmax) or (600:400)]

Comment: After several hops between your other question and this one, I'm still unclear about the size of things. It would help a lot if the declaration/dimensioning of relevant variables was clearly visible. At least for me.

Comment: Is the file being written and read on the same computer?  I;m wondering about possible endian issue.   If you don't have a reason for accessing the records in random order, I'd use `stream` rather than `direct` access, but that's just a preference.

Comment: Aww, the file is being written on a different computer than what it is being read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [M.S.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187997/m-s-b) suggests in a comment, this is an [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue between the machine that is writing the file and the machine that is reading.

To see this, look at the differences in these values at the same array index:

```
i-         600 j-         213 frp-  4.1759680E-08
i-         600 j-         213 frp-   13.6999998
```

If the first value `4.1759680E-08` is little endian, its hex representation is `33 33 5B 41`.  When this exact representation is read on a big endian machine, it reads as `13.6999998`.  If the first value is big endian and second little endian, the problem is the same except the hex representation is `41 5B 33 33` instead.  To fix the problem you need to determine the endianess of the machine that writes the file.

Both gfortran and Intel Fortran (and possible others) provide extensions that allow you to specify the byte ordering of an unformatted input file.  If the machine that wrote the file is big endian, add this to your `open` statement when reading:

```
convert='big_endian'
```

If the machine that wrote the file is little endian, add this to the `open` statement when reading:

```
convert='little_endian'
```

---

You indicated you are writing on a little endian machine so in order to read this on the big endian machine, open it as:

```
open(unit=io, file=trim(input), access='direct', iostat=ioer, &
        status='old', action='READ', recl=imax*jmax*4, &
        convert='little_endian')
```

and your read should work properly.

Comment: @Trish if you let me know what kind of computer wrote the file, I can be specific about which option above you need to use.

Comment: Thanks @casey, my machine (the `write`) is little_endian.

Comment: Woohoo, it worked!! I added `convert='little_endian' to my 'open' statement.

Comment: @Trish glad to hear it.  Something you might look at in the future is HDF5 or NetCDF. Both are a bit more work to use than raw Fortran IO, but you don't have to deal with portability issues like this and many software packages know how to read these formats.  They are particularly well suited to gridded data.

Comment: I would just stress more than the `convert=` specifier is no only non-standard, but also compiler specific. Other compilers use other means, and have more variants be it the  `-fconvert` or the  GFORTRAN_CONVERT_UNIT environment variable. Solaris Studio has `-xfilebyteorder` but not `convert=`. Because of this mess I use custom conversion routines instead.